# Loop not terminating after entering negative number

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm writing a program that is supposed to read in a list of positive integers(including 0). If the user enters more than 100 numbers or enters a negative number, the loop is supposed to terminate.

I tried doing a simple do-while loop to tackle this requirement but at runtime, no matter what number I provide, the loop never terminates. I've tried changing the loop around a few times and have been unsuccessful so far. I must have made a very subtle rookie mistake but I can't seem to catch it.

```
    int[] list = new int[100];
    int size=0;
    do{
        list[size] = kbd.nextInt();
        size++;
    }while((size < 100) && (list[size] >= 0));


}
```

Comment: Of course not. You just incremented `size`, so the value of the next element in `list` is `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you increment `size` before you test `list[size] >= 0`. You should change this to

```
do{
    list[size] = kbd.nextInt();
    size++;
}while((size < 100) && (list[size-1] >= 0));
```

Comment: @s24569 If your satisfied with the answer please consider accepting it after the 15 minute wait period by clicking the little green check mark underneath the score for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using a for-loop to do what you want? In my opinion for-loops are so much easier to use when working with arrays. Here is an example how to solve your problem using such a for-loop:

```
int[] list = new int[100];
int tmp;

//This loop will run 100 times because your list.length() is 100
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    tmp = kbd.nextInt(); //Saving user input temporary

    if(tmp < 0) //Exit loop when input is negative
        break;
    else   //Add input to list
        list[i] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: I just started programming recently but the instructor made it pretty clear that if we use a break statement inside an if conditional, he'll immediately knock off points. I would have done what you did if he wasn't hovering the threat of a bad grade over our heads

Comment: All right. But I can't really understand why your instructor would do this. This makes no sense. I mean limiting a software developer to use just one solution is stupid. Especially if you limit him to use not one of the best solutions...